# Finding web site maps on Visio 2010

Tags: website

I am trying to generate a Website map on Visio 2010 but cannot see the Software and Database option - the only ones I can see are Business, Flowchart, Gneral, Maps & Floor Plans, Network and Schedule. What am I missing here and why can't I see the Software and Database option?

Answer (score 1):

- If you have Visio Standard, it's normal as it's not included; [you'll need at least Visio Professional for that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896660).
- If you have Visio Professional or superior, did you make sure that you enabled all features during the install? Relaunching the installer will tell you if something is missing.